# Form with two submit buttons doing two different things

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form that I have two buttons on. One button should take the user to one php script and the other button would take the user two a different php script. However for some reason the buttons aren't doing anything. Here is the code.

```
    <script language="Javascript">
function OnButton1()
{
document.contactform.action = "../scripts/email-info.php"
// document.Form1.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window

document.contactform.submit();             // Submit the page

return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
document.contactform.action = "../scripts/email-info2.php"
//document.contactform.target = "_blank";    // Open in a new window

document.contactform.submit();             // Submit the page

return true;
}
</script
```

Then here is the actual form code:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contactform" method="post">
<fieldset>
<div id="holder">
<div id="formLeft">
<div class="txtlabel">Name* </div><div class="input-bg"><input type="text" 
name="name"       id="name" required></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="msgbox">
<div class="txtlabel">Tell Us About Your Business Needs</div>
<div class="message-bg">
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="9" cols="56" required></textarea><input 
name="formpage" type="hidden" value="<?=$pagename;?>" />
</div></div><div style="clear:both"></div><br /><br />
<input src="/submitbtn.jpg"  
name="submit" value="View Now" class="submit-button" onclick="OnButton1();"/>
<input src="/submitbtn.jpg"  
name="submit" value="Download Now" class="submit-button2" onclick="OnButton2();" />
</fieldset>

</form>
```

I've removed some of the submission fields to make it more easily viewable. But I get nothing when I click either button...Any thoughts??

Comment: If you uncomment the line: // document.Form1.target = "_blank"; 

Does it open a blank window?

Comment: Because your functions return the boolean "true", in the HTML `onclick` attribute try to put `onclick="return OnButton1();"` and `onclick="return OnButton2();"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is in input:

```
<input src="/submitbtn.jpg"  
  name="submit" value="View Now" class="submit-button" onclick="OnButton1();"/>
```

When you have a form:

```
document.contactform.submit
```

Javascript returns the input with name `submit`, not the `submit` function.

You could change the name of the input:

```
<input src="/submitbtn.jpg"  
  name="yourName" value="View Now" class="submit-button" onclick="OnButton1();"/>
```

Also, your inputs are not buttons, check [this](http://jsbin.com/danimemu/1/edit?html,js,output).

## Update

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23349579/680909) mentions HTML5 `formaction` attribute:

```
<form action=#">
    <buton formaction="script-1.php">submit one</button>
    <buton formaction="script-2.php">submit two</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I've added in the type button which I was missing that was due to it previously being a image. But that part is now corrected. However when I press either button nothing still happens. Here is the updated version.. http://jsbin.com/danimemu/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you have not changed input name: `<input src="/submitbtn.jpg"  
  name="**yourName**" value="View Now" class="submit-button" onclick="OnButton1();"/>
`

Comment: AHHH!! that works! But for some reason my "required" class on the fields is not working. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: what is your "required" class?

Comment: css is not present in jsbin, so it won't show the real appearance,

Comment: no by required I mean when I press either of the buttons typically on a submit button it says a alert that this field is required. But for some reason in this setup when I press the button and do not fill out the form it just processes regardless. Like on the name field is required.

Comment: Typically it just validates by using the required class in html5

Comment: it's required attribute I think, your code has no `required` anywhere.

Comment: yeah i have it in there. just odd it isn't working. not sure why.

Comment: If you are using HTML5 required attribute you should also use the formaction attribute on the submitter button and do not use this suggested JS. Because it simple destroys the HTML5 form submission algorythm. Simply use this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23349579/680909

Comment: thanks, I edited the answer, where could I read a little bit about the  submission algorithm?, something brief, I tried Google but I had not any summarised as I wanted

Comment: or you meant just the way HTML5 uses `formaction` to submit form to different actions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one mentioned formaction. It is a legal attribute (in HTML5) for the input and button tag in submit/image state and can be used to send form data to a different action page. http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Element/input.html (it is also valid in button too).

```
<form action=#">
    <buton formaction="script-1.php">submit one</button>
    <buton formaction="script-2.php">submit two</button>
</form>
```

In case you need to support IE9-, you simply can polyfill this, using [webshims](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Forms-forms).

```
<script src="webshims/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
    webshims.polyfill('forms');
</script>

<!-- now it also works with IE8/9 and other legacy browsers -->
<form action=#">
    <buton formaction="script-1.php">submit one</button>
    <buton formaction="script-2.php">submit two</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference to your form is

```
document.forms.contactform
```

and not

```
document.contactform
```

So, for example, the submit button should be:

```
document.forms.contactform.submit();
//       ^^^^^
```

The same correction should be applied to other references.